Woman investigates/moves into house that controls everything, kills a guy with a mirror, traps and tries to kill her
Movie starts out with a young couple sneaking onto property and the house wants them gone and either hoses them or turns on sprinklers. 
House is not occupied.
Young woman comes and moves into the house/wants to know more about the house.
A tall oval mirror is taken from the house to an older man's place and it 'breathes' and then explodes.. killing him.
The house traps the young woman and a man inside the house, turns up the AC to freezing, then turns up the heat. At some point the tall fireplace 'breathes' and explodes bricks at them trying to kill them.
I watched this on TV in either very late 70's or early 80's.
I thought I knew the name of it but when I looked up that movie name.. it wasn't it.
Thank you.

The film This House Possessed (1981) opens with a couple sneaking onto a property and the house decides to hose them with water. No one is residing in the house at this time.
A woman and man inquire and are shown around the house.
Later on there is an exploding mirror with an older man and at the main house the temperature goes haywire along with other shenanigans. Bricks at one point do indeed seem to breath and fire out in this scene.
This House Possessed (1981) a made for TV movie with Parker Stevenson and Lisa Eilbacher.
